# hls live streaming on android jwplayer

Tags: android, jwplayer, hlsl, http-live-streaming, jwplayer6

hi im trying to configure jwplayer to use android hls i have premium edition, but my link doesnt work on me device 4.1.1 and 4.2.3 and 4.3.2 i dont know what else i can do:

```
   <script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/9/jwplayer.js"></script>
<script>jwplayer.key="mykeyhere"</script>

<div id="my-video"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("my-video").setup({
file: "http://184.164.135.246:1935/videostreaming/videostreaming/playlist.m3u8",
width: "100%",
androidhls:true,
aspectratio: "16:9",
primary: "flash"
}
);

</script>
```

this is a working player http://www.streaming507.com/itelevision/1.html

that player is working good in nexus 5 with android L

thank you.

Comment: This link works for me on my 4.2.2 device.

Comment: why doesnt works on 4.4.3?

Comment: I have not checked that specific version of Android, but we have a 4.4.4 device that works fine here.

Comment: so code is good? i dont need to change anything? im not sure i sent email to support jwplayer too

Comment: what about on iOS works good? strange i have nexus 5 with kitkat 4.4.4 and shows error

Comment: Code is fine. It works on iOS.